# Django. Автоматическое заполнение шапки таблицы

Tags: python, django, база-данных, веб-программирование, таблицы

Помогите начинающему. Долго рыл в интернете, но решения не нашел.
Вывожу данные из модели в шаблон в виде таблицы.
Шапку таблицы приходится заполнять вручную.
Как можно автоматически заполнить поля шапки таблицы данными из модели?

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
class Dolgn(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    dolg = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.dolg
class Persons(models.Model):
    tab_no=models.IntegerField("Таб.номер", primary_key=True)
    fio=models.CharField("ФИО", max_length=255)
    dolg = models.ForeignKey(Dolgn, on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name=u"Должность")
    def __str__(self):
        return self.fio
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Persons

def index(request):
    objs=Persons.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'app/index.html', {'objs':objs})
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head><title></title></head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Таб.номер</th>
        <th>ФИО</th>
        <th>Должность</th>
    </tr>
    {% for item in objs %}
    <tr> 
         <td>{{ item.tab_no }}</td>
         <td>{{ item.fio }}</td>
         <td>{{ item.dolg }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

**Результат:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14496978/fields-verbose-name-in-templates